# How should I weight paint for shoulder Region?

Tags: mesh, armature, weight-painting

I was trying to make my character do wave in air but the mesh seems to fall off everytime.
I cannot identify the problem. See the images.
[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

[image: image4]

[image]

Comment: please share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Added the file.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to change the *IK Pole Angles* to -90° so that it doesn't deform your mesh:

[image]

Also you need to change the modifiers stack, this seems to be more logical (and enable the *Armature* modifier's *Preserve Volume* option):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The mesh appears to be pinching due to the rotation the arms are using to get into the wave position. Try bending the arms in a more natural way and adjusting weight paint. As of now the shoulder is rolling in such a way that along with the weight paint is causing the mesh to roll too far.